# BTEQ: Save Teradata error in logfile

Tags: teradata

My goal is to automate a deployment of SQL scripts to Teradata via BTEQ. So far my script is working. However, I would like to generate a log file where possible failures are captured.

```
.LOGON tdserver/username,pw
.EXPORT file=\logfile.txt;

.run file = \Desktop\test\test.sql;

.LOGOFF
.EXIT
```

My SQL script will create a VIEW. When this view for example already exists I see an error in the BTEQ command window:

*** Failure 3804 View 'ViewName' already exists.

I would like to have this TD Message in my log file. I tried several tings, have been looking for 3 hours but unfortunately without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may want to experiment using `.SET ERROROUT STDERR` which re-routes the error stream to the STDERR output file instead of the default action of routing the error stream to STDOUT.

There is more information in the BTEQ manual under Chapter 5 - BTEQ Commands.

Comment: Thank you very much. I will give it a check.

Comment: mm So far no success. I don't think I need to redirect it to STDERR.. I would like to save it from BTEQ straight to a file. Any ideas?

Comment: STDERR should be specified like a log file would be on the command line. It may require a redirection.

Comment: ok, one step further, now every line is stored in a logfile. However, I would like to see only the errors. Unfortunately this is really beyond my knowledge..

Comment: Got it! :) Thank a lot! C:\apps..\..\"Teradata BTEQ.exe" 2>c:\temp\error_output.txt

Answer (score 0):

Save all your script written above as a text file and create a batch file that generates a log after running the script:

```
echo off
bteq < script.txt > script.log 2>&1
@echo off goto end
:end
@echo exit
```

Errors will be recorded in this way.