# how to get error messages to a file in BTEQ for teradata

Tags: redirect, teradata

i write some SQL commands in batch file (.bteq files), the bteq file is as follows:

```
.logon localhost:1025/dbc,dbc

SELECT 1 FROM dbc.tables WHERE databasename = 'customerservice' AND TABLENAME 
= 'accounts';
.if activitycount <>0 then drop table customerservice.accounts;

CREATE SET TABLE CustomerService.accounts ,FALLBACK ,
 NO BEFORE JOURNAL,
 NO AFTER JOURNAL,
 CHECKSUM = DEFAULT,
 DEFAULT MERGEBLOCKRATIO
 (
  ACCOUNT_NUMBER INTEGER NOT NULL,
  STREET_NUMBER INTEGER,
  STREET CHAR(25) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  CITY CHAR(20) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  STATE CHAR(2) CHARACTER SET LATIN NOT CASESPECIFIC,
  ZIP_CODE INTEGER,
  BALANCE_FORWARD DECIMAL(10,2),
  BALANCE_CURRENT DECIMAL(10,2))
UNIQUE PRIMARY INDEX ( ACCOUNT_NUMBER );

insert into customerservice.accounts 
values(20031303,559,'LaSalleAve','SantaMonica','CA',94123,4550.00,4550.00);
insert into customerservice.accounts values(20033587,506,'SomersetWay',
'HermosaBeach','CA',90365,7770.00,7770.00);insert into
customerservice.accounts 
values(20033118,900,'9thStreet','HermosaBeach','CA',90365,3080.00,3080.00);
insert into customerservice.accounts values
(20032649,924,'OregonTrail','HermosaBeach','CA',90365,8200.00,8200.00);
insert into customerservice.accounts values
(20030691,987,'ComptonPlace','SantaMonica','CA',94123,8240.00,8240.00);
```

then i run this bteq file like this:

```
bteq < test.bteq 2>error.txt
```

what i want to is redirect error to error.txt, but seems it do not work, maybe it is because 2 is just for standard error, but the SQL error is not standard system error ? 
if so, then is there any ways we can redirect SQL error to a file ?

Comment: Been a while, but i think you can include this command in your script to redirect BTEQ errors to standard error: `.set errorout stderr`.

Comment: it works perfectly, thanks,

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BTEQ: Save Teradata error in logfile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36792868/bteq-save-teradata-error-in-logfile)